# Need help in c macros

Tags: c, macros

I have written a code but that does not work as I expect. I want to pass a string variable to a Macro and print.

```
#define XSTR(a) "/home/"STR(a)"/log"
#define STR(a)  #a 
int main()
{
    char *test = "user1";
    printf("%s", XSTR(test));
}
```

The above program prints "/home/test/log. But I want that to print "/home/user1/log". I know that preprocessor cant take a runtime value. But is there any way to acheive this?

Thanks,

Comment: Why do you need the macro?

Comment: When you do `#a`, the macro argument is **not** expanded. [Documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html)

Comment: Why do you need a macro to do this?

Comment: I have updated the question now. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: If you want to use the content of `test`, then you can't use macro string concatenation, you need actual real strcat or if you are happy with C++, you could use `std::string` and `+` to paste strings together - or put `user1` in your macro if you want to hard-code it in your code.

Comment: You should decide whether you're writing in C or C++, and then remove the tag for the other language. The current answers all assume that you're using C.

Answer (score 4):

Since you haven't provided any motivation for using a macro, the better solution might be to avoid it altogether:

```
printf("%s", test);
```

**Edit** Since you want to *print* something, you can do this:

```
printf("/home/%s/log", test);
```

Comment: I have updated the question now. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @test You can still use `printf` directly for that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes

```
#define STR(a)  (a)
int main()
{
    char *test = "printtest";
    printf("%s", STR(test));
}
```

in your macro you are stringifying the argument with the `#` token [stringizing operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wy090hkc.aspx).

Comment: Hi, that worked fine. actually i need to achieve something like this. I have edited the question. sorry for the trouble

Answer (score 2):

```
#define STR(a)  #a
```

makes argument (in your case a) a string literal.

If you do #blah, it will create string "blah".

so, when you are saying STR(test) you are just asking for a string "test".

test is already string with the value "printtest" - you do not need STR(test) around it to get string value.

What are you trying to achieve with STR(test)?

Addition after update:
Yes, for char constants you can merge them just by putting them one by one in a sequence:

```
printf("%s\n", "foo" "blah" "bar");
->fooblahbar
```

But, if you have char value which is not constant you can not merge them:

```
char *str="blah";
printf("%s\n", "foo" str "bar");
```

this won't compile :-(

What you need here is snprintf():

```
char *str="blah";
char buf[BUFSZ];
snprintf(buf, BUFSZ, "/home/%s/log", str);
```

now buf contains your desired string:

```
printf("%s\n", buf);
/home/blah/log
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, it *is* possible to do it by relying on the automatic concatenation of adjoining string literals:

```
#define XSTR(a) "/home/" a "/log"
int main()
{
    #define test "user1"
    printf("%s", XSTR(test));
    #undef test
}
```

This will resolve to

```
int main() { printf("%s", "/home/" "user1" "/log"));
```

Which in turn resolves to

```
int main() { printf("%s", "/home/user1/log"));
```

#### However

There is no reason at all to use a macro in this case. It also relies on a compile-time mechanism, and thus will not work if you try to choose `test` at runtime.